# Get data cached in Windows AppFabric Caching Service

Tags: c#, appfabric

I wanna get the whole which is been cached in Microsoft AppFabric.

Also, is there any method to get it and check the filesize of the data in cache?

Comment: Actually have you tried to use Windows Azure AppFabric SDK ?

Comment: What do you mean by cached in appfabric?  appfabric is a service to deploy applications to the cloud.  Are you referring to blob storage? the service defination? Table Service??

Comment: i installed appfabric and enabled caching in appfabric. Now i wanna get the whole data from cache.

Comment: @bryanmac Windows Server AppFabric is a distributed caching service

Comment: OK - I thought you were referring to the Azure AppFabric

Answer (score 0):

[This blog post by Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingConfiguringAndUsingWindowsServerAppFabricAndTheVelocityMemoryCacheIn10Minutes.aspx) is a good place to start if you are just starting out using AppFabric as your caching service.

Comment: thats a nice one..but can you tell me how i can check cache empty or not?

Comment: If you wanted to do this you would need to know what region your data was stored in and then you could use GetObjectsInRegion

Comment: This should rather be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Get-CacheStatistics powershell cmdlet to get the filesize of all of the items in the cache:

Get-CacheStatistics Cache1

This is sample output from the previous command.

Size         : 12408186

ItemCount    : 1200

RegionCount  : 714

RequestCount : 1200

MissCount    : 1200

See more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921010.aspx